# Best approach to extend this C++ factory implementation?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory

I would like to extend an existing piece of code, and I'm not sure about the cleanest design approach to do so. I'm wondering if the existing design really supports the kind of extension that I'm thinking of.

There is a factory which looks like this:

```
class XYZFactory
{
public:
  static XYZFactory& getDefaultInstance() // so this is a singleton!
  // ... some create methods
  // std::unique_ptr<ABC> createABC();
private:
  std::unique_ptr<XYZFactoryImpl> m_impl;
}
---
XYZFactory::XYZFactory() : m_impl(std::make_unique<XYZImpl>;
```

Now the problem is that I would like to extend the functionality of XYZImpl by deriving from it. I would like to avoid to expose that implementation detail however in the factory class, like adding a separate XYZFactory constructor with a ExtendedXYZImpl as an argument to inject that extension.

ADDED/EDITED for clarifaction: I should have called XYZImpl XYZFactoryImpl. It does the actual object creation. XYZFactory passes the createWhatever() calls to it. There is only one instance of XYZImpl which is held in m_Impl.
The thing that I actually want to be able to dynamically change is a member of XYZImpl m_ABC (instance of ABC) which is used for the object creation. I would like to derive from ABC.

Would killing the singleton design and subclassing from XYZFactory help?

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Mark

Comment: Do not think there is a completely clean solution, personally I would not subclass a factory I would just change it or if you want to keep your code separate I would consider a delegation, but as I said above that does not look that much cleaner.

Comment: What is `XYZImpl`?  What does the `XYZFactory` constructor look like?

Comment: @Mark: can you detail what you mean by "with a ExtendedXYZImpl as an argument to inject that extension"; add some pseudo-code to show what you expect from XYZFactory.

Comment: @JohnZwinck XYZ forwards the create methods to XYZImpl where the actual object creation is done. The XYZFactory is the one from above, it only initializes m_Impl with an instance with XYZImpl. Not sure if this is a best practice in C++? It kind of looks like abstract factory methods, except that XYZ is actually not abstract.

XYZImpl also has a reference to an instance of ABC, which is really the thing that I would like to extend. ABC is passed to the constructors of some of the classes that are instantiated in the create methods, but I would like to be able to pass a derived ABC instead.

Comment: @shrike injecting was what I would like to avoid, so it was meant to be an example approach that I would not like to take. What I was thinking there was to add XYZImpl as argument to the getDefaultInstance() method and the XYZ constructor, so that I can inject the derived XYZImpl instead of creating the default one.

Answer (score 0):

`XYZFactory` currently has a dependency on `XYZFactoryImpl` so clearly there is no way of injecting a dependency on `ExtendedXYZImpl` without exposing that functionality on `XYZFactory`. If that is unacceptable, the only alternative is to abandon the current design of `XYZFactory`.

There are not a great deal of constraints left in your question for us to use to form an answer but I suggest you start by making `XYZFactory` an abstract factory:

```
class XYZFactory {
public:
  virtual ~XYZFactory(){}
  virtual std::unique_ptr<ABC> createABC() const = 0;
}
```

With two implementations:

```
class XYZFactoryImpl : public XYZFactory {
public:
  std::unique_ptr<ABC> createABC() const override {
    return std::make_unique<ABC>();
  }
};

class ExtendedXYZFactoryImpl : public XYZFactory {
public:
  std::unique_ptr<ABC> createABC() const override {
    return std::make_unique<DerivedABC>();
  }
};
```

You can then provide a function to get a singleton instance and a way of reseating with a different singleton instance. e.g:

```
namespace details {  
  // Or this could be hidden in an anonymous namespace in a .cpp file
  std::unique_ptr<XYZFactory>& getXYZFactoryInstanceMutable() {
    static std::unique_ptr<XYZFactory> singleton = std::make_unique<XYZFactoryImpl>();
    return singleton;
  }
}

const XYZFactory& getXYZFactoryInstance() {
  auto& singleton = details::getXYZFactoryInstanceMutable();
  if (!singleton)
      throw std::runtime_error("No XYZFactory registered");
  return *singleton;
}

void setXYZFactoryInstance(std::unique_ptr<XYZFactory> new_factory) {
  details::getXYZFactoryInstanceMutable() = std::move(new_factory);
}
```

Then to inject in your `ExtendedXYZFactoryImpl` you could do:

```
setXYZFactoryInstance(std::make_unique<ExtendedXYZFactoryImpl>());

auto abc = getXYZFactoryInstance().createABC();
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/TqcGOg).